# When deploying a blog, is it best to use a subdomain or a subfolder (SEO Benefits)?

Tags: seo, blogs

I know this is a common question, and there are resources on the internet about this topic, but I wanted to here from this community everyone's thoughts on subdomain vs subfolder when deploying a blog (SEO Benefits).

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place for "SEO" questions.

Comment: These options are not mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this once, and based on community feedback as well as weighing in the pros and cons, I'd say go for a folder, for more info:

http://www.v7n.com/forums/seo-forum/30267-folders-versus-subdomains.html

Answer (score 0):

Both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not being an expert on this, I'd say both will do the same but I prefer a folder because, depending on the server/host you're using, a subdomain might take a while to be visible to everyone.
This is based on the fact one of the hosts I use taking 2 days to guarantee visibility of a subdomain.

I'm sorry but I don't know enough to explain why this happens.

Hope it helped :)

Cheers

Comment: Regarding SEO, I think it doesn't depend on which solution you chose but again, someone needs to confirm this :) (I also want to know hehe)